# Set select list option value

Tags: forms

I'm trying to set value of select list programmatically with hook form alter

I have select list with options:

```
$options = array(125 => 'USA');
```

and setting value like this

```
$form['field_news_rubrique']['und']['#options'] = $options
```

But this don't work.

if i change options like this

```
$options = array(0 => 'USA');
```

it's working

if i have multiple value in options like this :

```
$options = array(124=> 'EN', 125 => 'USA');
```

it's working too

Comment: I'm get it working by disable taxonomy term permission module

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set the value before submission or after?

Before submission:
Use $form and set the default value for the select list using the key.

After submission:
Use $form_state['values']

Comment: I want to set value before submission , but i get it working thank's for your post